# The correct way to fit a polynomial trend in time series (with R)

Tags: r, time-series

What is the correct way to fit a polynomial trend in time series on R?

I've tried the following below and they all yield to different results:

```
## Modeling quadratic trend ##
library(astsa)                              # need for jj dataset
library(forecast)

# approach 1 - with lm
t_trend = time(jj) - 1960                   # 1960 is start of TS
summary( lm(log(jj) ~ 0 + I(t_trend^2) ))

# approach 2 - with forecast::tslm
summary( tslm(log(jj) ~ 0 + **I**(trend^2) ))
```

For what it's worth, the results from approach 1 estimates are *very* different than the output from approach 2 and EViews.

Approach 1 output

```
Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
I(t_trend^2) 0.0075709  0.0001813   41.76   <2e-16 ***
```

The results from approach 2 estimates are similar to EViews.

Approach 2 output

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
I(trend^2) 4.597e-04  1.082e-05   42.49   <2e-16 ***
```

Screenshot below is the output from EViews:

`LS LOG(JJ) @TREND^2`

[image]

Comment: Hi: check out the poly function by doing ?poly. It's in base R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two give the same results

```
# approach 1 - with lm
t_trend = 4*(time(jj) - 1960) +1                  # 1960 is start of TS
summary( lm(log(jj) ~ 0 + I(t_trend^2) ))

# approach 2 - with forecast::tslm
summary( tslm(log(jj) ~ 0 + I(trend^2) ))
```

The `I()` is not optional.

The multiplication by 4 wouldn't affect forecasts, so if that's your goal either way would be ok. I can't say why EViews is different, since you don't say what model you fit or what results you got.

Comment: Thank you Professor! I added the "I" to approach 2, and the output now looks pretty close to EViews. However, the estimates from approach 1 is very much different than the estimates from approach 2 and EViews. Do you have any ideas why this is? I don't understand why the "trend" from Hyndman package yields different result from just manually creating the trend from time().